# OneDrive app not working in 8.1, folder & OneDrive Icon missing

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I'm trying to get Microsoft OneDrive to work on my business laptop. The Windows 7 Client works great at home, but i have a Windows 8.1 Laptop at work, where you HAVE to use the integrated OneDrive app. I connected my MS-Account to the local user on my laptop in order to have access to OneDrive.

Opening OneDrive only shows "An error occured when trying to open the save location. Try again" (From german: "Beim Öffnen des Speicherorts ist ein Fehler aufgetreten")

There is no OneDrive folder in C:\Users\, not in %HOMEDRIVE% or anywhere else.

In regedit, in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SkyDrive there is no "UserFolder" Key. I tried to manually create one, but it keeps getting removed by OneDrive.

I ran the troubleshooter app. If i have "UserFolder" manually created in the registry, it removes the entry. If there is no "UserFolder", the troubleshooter app gives me the error message "OneDrive needs access to the folder "", which is unavailable. If the location is on this PC, make sure the device or drive is connected or the disc is inserted, and then try again."

I just moved from DropBox to OneDrive and try to get it to work properly... I'm using my Laptop at work for some time now, but only now tried to open OneDrive for the first time.

My colleague with an identical laptop and also Windows 8.1 receives some kind of "First Run"-Welcome window when opening OneDrive, where he can setup OneDrive and everything...

Comment: Your user profile seems to be corrupt.  I would create a new user then link that profile to your Microsoft Account.  If that doesn't work then you have serious system integrity and permission problems that are easily solved by restoring your system image.

Comment: I wiped my user profile yesterday and got a new one from our admins. The profile is as fresh as it can be.

Comment: Did you use the same name or a different name and did you delete the user profile folder before doing so?  What about a different machine does this still happen?

Comment: I did delete the profile folder and i didnt copy anything from AppData from my backup into the new profile. The profile was removed, even from the domain server, and then i logged in. Then Windows acted like it's my first login into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SkyDrive

I tried the following things :

added 'UserFolder' pointing to my OneDrive folder.

Run the troubleshooter. No error message. Didn't fix though.

Changed 'RedirectingRootFolder' from 1 to 0.

Run the troubleshooter again. Didn't fix either.

Deleted the OneDrive folder from disk.

Run the troubleshooter again.

Everything back to normal, directory created, start syncing, all files back !!

Comment: Great answer, but sadly, did not fix the problem. I followed your description, but after running the troubleshooter after deleting the folder, the troubleshooter "cleared" my registry again.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but I eventually got this to work by following VKP's instructions. The thing that caught me out was my files are actually in C:\Users\\SkyDrive, not in the more obvious C:\Users\\OneDrive. Once I completely deleted that SkyDrive folder and set the UserFolderLocation key to the correct place, the OneDrive tray icon magically appeared and the app started syncing properly.

Hopefully this helps someone!